# Ridge logistic regression with SAS?

Tags: sas, regression, logistic-regression

How can one do Logistic Regression optimized with a ridge regression, in SAS? According to comments [here](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/03/20/compute-ridge-regression.html) and [here](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Statistical-Procedures/Ridge-in-logistic-regression/td-p/208301) this should already be implemented in SAS with PROC HPGENSELECT. But how?

I am new to SAS, having come from the world of R. I am a little disoriented and having a generally hard time finding R-analogues in SAS.

Comment: The last I looked, only (in SAS) Proc REG has the capability to perform Ridge regression.

Answer (score 0):

Only the LASSO options on the `PROC HPGENSELECT` [Statement](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetVersion=14.2&docsetTarget=statug_hpgenselect_syntax01.htm&locale=en#statug.hpgenselect.proc_lassorho) are available.  The default optimization routine uses [ridging](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetVersion=14.2&docsetTarget=statug_hpgenselect_details36.htm&locale=en#statug.hpgenselect.details_nrridg) when required.  There are no options that I can find that allow you to control the ridging.

```
proc hpgenselect data=blah lassorho=2 lassosteps=100 ;
<other stuff>
model <model specification>;
<other stuff>
run;
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Unlike Lasso which is based on adding an L1 penalty, ridge regression adds a multiple of the L2 norm to be minimized, where the multiple might be tuned by the analyst. It's not clear to me from your answer or the documentation which parameter controls this tuning multiple. I take it from your answer that you claim that lassorho=2 means that we are adding an L2 penalty?

Comment: Sorry, no.  I misunderstood and based my answer on the SAS blog you referenced.  Let me look further if there is a way to specify that parameter.

Comment: Based on a closer reading (sorry) only the LASSO method is available.  The default optimization uses a ridging method for decomposition of the hessian.  You can read about it http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetVersion=14.2&docsetTarget=statug_hpgenselect_details36.htm&locale=en#statug.hpgenselect.details_nrridg.  Will update the answer.

Comment: It's a shame, because it's such a basic procedure for an analyst. I am trying, but struggling to appreciate SAS.

Comment: By the way, I don't think their use of Newton-Raphson with ridging has anything directly to do with Ridge Regression. I think it's just their way of quickly and robustly calculating the maximum likelihood.

Comment: The ridging is applying a shrinkage parameter to the hessian when needed.  Same idea as a ridge regression (minus the 'when needed' part).  Both are used to correct for collinearity in the X`X matrix, right?

Comment: I think you are technically right, but practically there is a big difference. Unless I am misunderstanding one only needs to add a very tiny regularization for the computation "when needed" to speed up computation. But for ridge regression one aims to penalize large coefficients, and you need more than a tiny regularization. Of course I don't know exactly what's going on under the hood with SAS, since they leave you to guess.

Comment: consider using a Bayesian MCMC model?

Answer (score 0):

Inside SAS software family, there is no procedure directly covering the Ridge Regression this question inquired about. Ridge= option here and there on optimization routines are NOT ridge regression. You may visit lexjansen.com to search for ridge regression. There are published programs that methodically carry out what you want, mix of Base and IML, but IML is not necessarily required depending on your custom needs.